# How to share several domains on one IP?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, domain, subdomain

I have external static IP, one domain in com zone, free dns provider and home pc with wifi router.

Domain was delegated to my IP and localhost works perfect.

I did it using PORT FORWARDING RULES (wifi-router option): any request on my IP will be redirected on internal IP.

I've created subdmoain and added this zone to dns provider, but I cannot get subdomain page doing external request (from another PC). Internal request on my PC (from my PC) works fine at the same time.

So how to delegate subdomain? Why it doesn't work?

Comment: This is off topic here due to it being a non-professional environment. You may have better luck over on Superuser or Unix & Linux, but before asking on either of those sites, spend some time researching Name-based virtual hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What IP did you provide in DNS for this subdomain? You need to provide your external static IP, not internal/local on your network. If this is not a case and remote computer see your subdomain with external IP (ping the subdomain and check what IP does it ping), what is your vhost configuration? Without more information about your environment we can't help you more.

Comment: I provided external IP for DNS but didn't provide external IP for /etc/hosts - that is my bad. Thanks!